# Concatenating Pandas DataFrames not as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to append 3 columns from one dataFrame to the end of another, similar to the following:

```
    df1:
    a b c d
    1 1 4 1
    2 4 1 5

    df2[colsOfInterest]:
    e f
    3 5 
    1 1
```

Using newDF = pd.concat([df1,df2[colsOfInterest]])

I am expecting:

```
    a b c d e f
    1 1 4 1 3 5
    2 4 1 5 1 1
```

But I am getting:

```
   a b c d e f
   1 1 4 1 NA NA 
   2 4 1 5 NA NA
   NA NA NA NA 3 5
   NA NA NA NA 1 1
```

**Update:**
Although I can't post my dataFrames, I seemed to have narrowed it down to the data type or consistency. If I write both df's to a file using to_csv, then read them back into new ones with read_csv, the concat process works fine.

One of them is completely object type, and the other float64.

When re-reading them, they turn into a mix of float64,int64,object.
If I try to take the originals, and convert them to numeric types by .astype(str).convert_numeric, the types match the read versions, however the concat still fails.

Comment: if @user1827356's solution isn't working please update your question with the entire output from the terminal of df1 and df2 i.e. including their indices.

Comment: The example I showed works, however fails with my (much larger) dataFrames. I will try and post a specific representative case that fails.

Comment: @jzalger the reason might be that your indexes do not match. As Andy and DSM mentioned use pd.concat([df1.reset_index(), df2[colsOfInterest].reset_index()], axis=1)

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
pd.concat([df1, df2[colsOfInterest]], axis=1)
```

Comment: All this seems to do is reverse the concat order (ie:
NA NA NA NA 3 5
instead of
1 1 4 1 NA NA

Comment: @jzalger if there is an issue with the index, you can pass ignore_index=True.

Comment: @AndyHayden: I found that I had to explicitly `reset_index()`-- `ignore_index` didn't do what I thought it did.